# Why is my A.T*A (A transpose A) matrix singular?

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, independence, linear-algebra, singular-matrix

I'm running into an wall on my intuition when using least squares. I'm trying to simulate some data, for fun, and I'm getting a result that says my (A.T * A) matrix is singular.

In order to condense the problem, here's a simplified version of the code.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[-2, -2, 4],
               [0,  0, 0],
               [2,  2, 4],
               [3,  3, 9]])

x = np.matrix([[1, 2, .2]]).T
b = A*x

x_hat = (A.T*A).I * A*b
```

I don't get a value for x_hat, because `(A.T*A)` is singular and can't be inverted.

In this example, say my columns are as follows `A = [X, Y, X*Y]` and I'm taking my samples for b at those exact locations for the independent variables (X and Y), why can't I run the least squares regression on my data?

I realize that col1 and col2 and not independent, but in practice this is a completely feasible real life sample, albeit not a very good sampling technique.

Comment: "I realize that col1 and col2 (are) not independent": this is exactly what makes $A^TA$ singular. So it's not clear what the question is.

Comment: I guess my question is, why doesn't it work in practice? The data is there, so why can't the math resolve that x_hat should be [1, 2, .2]?

Comment: If columns are linearly depended you can't invert a square matrix. Your questions suggest that you have a fundamental misunderstand of what you are actually doing. I was about to suggest that you may want to use regularization but I feel it is better that you first get an understanding of what you are actually doing

Comment: After further thought, this is what I trying to figure out:
There isn't enough information here to resolve difference between a change due to X and a change due to Y. A valid solution is [1,2,.2], but another valid  solution is [3,0,.2]. There are inf many solutions so you can't resolve an exact answer for x_hat. 

New question: is there a way that is as clean and simple as `(A.T*A).I*A.T*b`, but to get an equation for the whole group of solutions?

Answer (score 2):

After further thought, this is what I trying to figure out:

There isn't enough information here to resolve difference between a change due to X and a change due to Y. A valid solution is [1,2,.2], but another valid solution is [3,0,.2]. There are inf many solutions, so you can't resolve an exact answer for x_hat.